# Angular 4 CSS not rendering after Tree Shaking

Tags: javascript, angular, tree-shaking

I'm using the Rollup plugin to do a Tree shaking of my Angular application.
I get a final `build.js` and when I inspect it, the `CSS` is there but for some reason it's not being rendered by the DOM.

I'm using `SCSS` and all my styles have a `.scss` extension

`rollup-config.js`

```
import rollup from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'
import scss from 'rollup-plugin-scss'

//paths are relative to the execution path
export default {
  input: 'src/main-aot.js',
  output: {
    file: 'aot/dist/build.js', // output a single application bundle
    format: 'iife',
  },
  sourcemap: true,
  sourcemapFile: 'aot/dist/build.js.map',
  onwarn: function (warning) {
    // Skip certain warnings

    // should intercept ... but doesn't in some rollup versions
    if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') { return; }

    // console.warn everything else
    console.warn(warning.message);
  },
  plugins: [
    scss(),
    nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, module: true }),
    commonjs({
      include: ['node_modules/**']
    }),
    uglify()
  ]
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular Tour of Heroes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/7bceea02f5.js"></script>

    <script src="shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="zone.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>
  <script async src="dist/build.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Which css file(s) are you referring to? Could it be a ViewEncapsulation issue?

Comment: No, its not related. I'm manually converting SCSS to CSS  using node sass and gulp. So if i solve this I don't have to do that anymore.